# Restricting the domain of a function plotted on Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a set of data on Gnuplot, and want to superimpose the function `x^2` on the same plot.  I can do this like so:

```
plot "filename" using 1:2, x**2
```

Which produces a plot in which the function `x^2` stretches across the whole domain of the graph.  I would like to make it such that the function is only shown on a small stretch of the graph, say from x=1 to x=2, while the size of the graph is dictated by `filename` to be from x=0 to x=10.  I know that to plot the function by itself I could do:

```
plot [1:2] x**2
```

But how would I keep the superimposition together, given that what I tried intuitively did not work:

```
plot "filename" using 1:2, [1:2] x**2

invalid expression
```

The documentation seems to be hard to interpret when it comes to getting this to work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way may be to define a piecewise function using the ternary operator `?`:

```
f(x) = (x > 1 && x < 2) ? x**2 : 1/0
plot "filename" using 1:2, f(x)
```

Another way is with the `replot` command:

```
plot "filename" using 1:2
replot [1:2] x**2
```

Comment: but this piecewise function shows a discontinuity ion the plot! Do you know how to remove that? Thanks for the answer you posted by the wey.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a discontinuity in the plot. When I plot f(x) I get x^2 from 1 to 2, as ordered. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @andyas Thank you for your quick reply! I mean the jump from 0 to the next value, since this function is not piecewise continuous. Cheers

Comment: Do you mean the jump from 1 to the first point plotted (slightly above 1)? That is because the function f(x) is sampled only at discrete points. The number of those points is determined by the `set sample` command--that might help.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is an old question, but for anyone who might be looking for an easier way:

Your first idea

```
plot "filename" using 1:2, [1:2] x**2
```

works now.

Comment: In 5.2, `[1:2] x**2` just sets the initial zoom of the plot, it doesn't restrict the domain. Is that different in later versions?

Comment: @TomAnderson what do you mean exactly? I get the desired result in 5.2 and 5.4. However, if you do `plot  [1:2] x**2, "filename" using 1:2,` the data of the file will be limited to `[1:2]` as well. And if you do  `plot  [1:2] x**2, [0:10] "filename" using 1:2,` the range of the data file will _not_ be expanded to `[0:10]`. It's not intuitive but I guess it has some reasons "behind the scenes".

Comment: @theozh Trying this again (still using 5.2), i can't exactly reproduce what you are saying. [Here is a complete example with data and plot commands](https://gist.github.com/tomwhoiscontrary/6586e7e82a8ccb590f09e2f2859bd5a7). If i do `plot "file.dat" using 1:2 with lines, [1:3] sin(x)`, then the domain of the function is indeed limited. But if i do `plot [1:3] sin(x), "file.dat" using 1:2 with lines`, then the function goes to infinity, and all the data in the file is plotted; only the initial zoom is changed.

Comment: @TomAnderson what do you mean with "function goes to infinity"? In your case 3 and 4 my graph is limited to [1:3]. Which version do you have 5.2.0 or 5.2.8?