# Gnuplot to plot discrete arcs in polar coordinate

Tags: gnuplot, polar-coordinates, piecewise

When I used Gnuplot to plot two discrete arcs in polar coordinate, I encountered the following problem.

For example:

```
reset    
r2 = 1
set polar
set size ratio 1 1,1
plot [0:2./3.*pi] r2, [pi:5./3.*pi] r2
```

This generated wrong result:
[image]

If I replaced the last piece of code by:

```
plot [pi:5./3.*pi] r2*0.8,  [0:2./3.*pi] r2
```

The result is still wrong.
[image]

How could I get the correct result in which one arc is on the top quadrant and the other is on the low quadrant please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching on internet, inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270563/restricting-the-domain-of-a-function-plotted-on-gnuplot/14270709#14270709) by andyras, I provide an answer to my own question here:

```
reset    
r2 = 1
set polar
set size ratio 1 1,1
set trange [0:2.*pi] noreverse nowriteback

fL(t)=t<=2./3.*pi ? r2 : 1/0
fR(t)=(t>=pi && t<=5./3.*pi) ? 0.8*r2 : 1/0

plot fL(t) with lines ls 1 lw 2,fR(t) with lines ls 1 lw 2 lc rgb 'red'
```

[image]