# How can you connect two plotted functions with vertical line (using GNUPLOT)?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

Let's say you want to plot a "step" function like this[image]

If you define f1(x) = 0 and f2(x) = 1, you can type

```
plot [-2:0] f1(x) t "f1" ls 1, [0:2] f2(x) t "f2" ls 1
```

but this would give you the graph without the vertical line, which connects f1(x) and f2(x). 
What is the best way to get the graph with the vertical line?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.gnuplotting.org/defining-piecewise-functions/  or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14270709/2836621

Comment: The first one helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, good luck with your project!